# autoconf not generating makefile?

Tags: unix, configure, autoconf

I am currently trying to create an installation package, using autoconf to generate the configure file. I have successfully managed to auto generate these, however, when I run `./configure`, no makefile is generated from `Makefile.in`.

My question is : **how do I debug this issue in order to narrow down why it is failing?**

The following is the error message I get when attempting to generate the Makefile :

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool
```

Comment: More Autoconf junk. That project should die and burn to the ground so something better can grow.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem when I upgraded autotools version, in my case the configure.ac file was missing the following line:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([1.9 foreign])
```

(Insert whatever version or options you need)

Then run `autoreconf --install`.

To answer the question about debugging: I went and looked at similar configure.ac files and worked through the differences until the error went way.

Comment: How is that an answer ? What exactly fixed it ?

Comment: Good point. I have re-read the original question (rather than the problem I was solving) and added a clarification.

Comment: In my case the line was already there, `autoreconf --install` was all that was needed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check that `configure.ac` contains something like:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Otherwise it won't create the makefile for you.

If it's not that, `config.log` should have clues about what's going wrong.

Comment: the above are generated within the configure.ac, trouble is i don't know what i am looking for within the config.log

Comment: here is an error message i have found configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, it turns out i needed to get rid of the ac_dirs from the configure file, this fixed the issue

Comment: You may want to accept an answer, be it yours if it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, and found it was due to the following line in `configure.ac`:

```
AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR([build-aux])
```

The line wasn't bad per se, however it needed to be moved closer to the top of the `configure.ac` file.